# Text not blinking in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

> I am learning about how to add style and color in text using bash script. This is the code I came across

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is a basic bash script.
flashred="\033[5;31;40m"
red="\033[31;40m"
none="\033[0m"
echo -e $flashred"ERROR: "$none$red"Something went wrong."$none
```

Now what I wanted at the output in terminal was that

> "ERROR" will **blink** while the part "Something went wrong." will just have **color applied to it**.

But when I run this file, colors are getting applied but the text "ERROR" is not blinking.

What mistake am I doing here?Any help will be appreciated.Thanks..:)

Comment: Working fine on `bash` on `Mac os X`, `GNU bash, version 4.3.46`

Comment: I am also using 4.3.46 on Ubuntu 16.04. But I don't know why it's not working.:(

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: Blinking isn't supported by most terminals. See this: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/97869-how-blink-terminal.html

Comment: @Inian. My filename was file1.sh so using ./file1.sh in terminal.

Comment: On Linux, you can try it on `xterm`. That works

Comment: @hek2mgl. Thanks for that post.It was very helpful.But I couldn't understand one thing why does it run on mac but not on Ubuntu? I mean they have the same bash version also.?

Comment: It's not related to the shell. It's related to the *terminal* you are using. Nowadays the terminal is most likely a *pseudo* terminal, meaning a software implementation. Like `gnome-terminal`, `terminator` or `xterm` on Linux or `iterm` on MAC. The blinking feature must be supported by those applications.

Comment: And I am using Gnome.Got it.I don't know why there is no support but still thanks for the help.:)

Comment: I guess the majority of users was just scared of having blinking output on terminal. That's why they dismissed that feature. I mean, it might be *cool* for a play-around project. But do you want to have a blinking terminal output as a system administrator when doing real work?

Comment: I have just started learning about bash scripts and everything and this blinking thing was pretty cool that's why i wanted to give it a try.And i don't know about real work but if it will be useful in any case then why not.:)

Comment: Konsole Version 16.04.3 in KDE Frameworks 5.28.0 with "Allow blinking text" checked on Advanced Tab of Settings -> "Edit Current Profile" has your whole text red with "ERROR:" blinking.

Comment: @hek2mgl Replace "scared of" with "annoyed by", and you've got it just about right.

Comment: what do you get for echo $TERM on your prompt?

Comment: @UselessPerson..xterm-256color: command not found. Is it related someway?

Answer (score -2):

It happens just because of any application, like anaconda, android ... etc., have installed; but when you update the Ubuntu by `sudo apt update` it will not update that package/software.
So update that paticularly and use them.

Comment: I tried to improve the readability of your post with some punctutation and capitalisation. I hope I did not break anything. I had to drop the "that why ?" part, which did make no sense whatsoever to me. Please [edit] to fix anything I broke and accept my apology in that case.